# Complete documentation of the iOS Settings app's URL scheme

Tags: ios, settings, url

The iOS Settings app provides an URL scheme (`prefs:`) which can be used to open the app directly on a particular page from other apps, in particular, shortcut apps such as [Launch Center](http://appcubby.com/launch-center/).

There are [various](http://www.iphonehacks.com/2011/11/how-to-create-custom-home-screen-shortcuts-for-settings-toggles-without-jailbreaking.html) [pages](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2011/11/11/how-to-create-custom-shortcuts-to-wifi-settings-airplane-mode-and-more-no-jailbreak-required/) on the web that have a list of some of the URLs, but these pages all seem to provide the same subset, and I know there is [at least one shortcut](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2011/11/11/how-to-create-custom-shortcuts-to-wifi-settings-airplane-mode-and-more-no-jailbreak-required/#comment-361963429) that's not included. In fact, I'd imagine that *every* page in Settings will have it's own URL.

Can anyone provide the complete list of URLs for the Settings app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I stumbled upon this excellent repo with even more URLs than listed above. The URLs have changed over time since these answers were written but this repo is very comprehensive and up to date at the time of writing.

https://github.com/FifiTheBulldog/ios-settings-urls/blob/master/settings-urls.md

Comment: Nice! Looks like the MacStories page hasn't been updated since 2019, so switching my accepted answer over to this one, which includes way more recent updates. (Taking your word for it that it's also more comprehensive.)

Comment: @Rich Thanks for updating, yes I did a quick count and it looks like MacStories article had about 130 URLs whereas the Github document has a whopping 370 URLs!

Comment: I did find another medium article that is also detailed. You may find it through this [url](https://medium.com/@contact.jmeyers/complete-list-of-ios-url-schemes-for-apple-settings-always-updated-20871139d72f).

Comment: i assume there is no way we can change or take an action using the URLs?

Answer (score 10):

As of iOS 13.1, these URLs are *back*, and have been [exhaustively documented on the MacStories website](https://www.macstories.net/ios/a-comprehensive-guide-to-all-120-settings-urls-supported-by-ios-and-ipados-13-1/) by Federico Viticci. Please note that the linked page is being actively updated, and contains other useful background and tips such as how to link to the settings for third party apps, so probably a good idea to follow the linke through to that site for the full info:

Settings URLs
iCloud

```
iCloud: prefs:root=CASTLE
iCloud Backup: prefs:root=CASTLE&path=BACKUP
```

Wireless Radios

```
Wi-Fi: prefs:root=WIFI
Bluetooth: prefs:root=Bluetooth
Cellular: prefs:root=MOBILE_DATA_SETTINGS_ID
```

Personal Hotspot

```
Personal Hotspot: prefs:root=INTERNET_TETHERING
Personal Hotspot ⇾ Family Sharing: prefs:root=INTERNET_TETHERING&path=Family%20Sharing
Personal Hotspot ⇾ Wi-Fi Password: prefs:root=INTERNET_TETHERING&path=Wi-Fi%20Password
```

VPN

```
VPN: prefs:root=General&path=VPN
```

Notifications

```
Notifications: prefs:root=NOTIFICATIONS_ID
Notifications ⇾ Siri Suggestions: prefs:root=NOTIFICATIONS_ID&path=Siri%20Suggestions
```

Sounds

```
Sounds: prefs:root=Sounds
Ringtone: prefs:root=Sounds&path=Ringtone
```

Do Not Disturb

```
Do Not Disturb: prefs:root=DO_NOT_DISTURB
Do Not Disturb ⇾ Allow Calls From: prefs:root=DO_NOT_DISTURB&path=Allow%20Calls%20From
```

Screen Time

```
Screen Time: prefs:root=SCREEN_TIME
Screen Time ⇾ Downtime: prefs:root=SCREEN_TIME&path=DOWNTIME
Screen Time ⇾ App Limits: prefs:root=SCREEN_TIME&path=APP_LIMITS
Screen Time ⇾ Always Allowed: prefs:root=SCREEN_TIME&path=ALWAYS_ALLOWED
```

General

```
General: prefs:root=General
General ⇾ About: prefs:root=General&path=About
General ⇾ Software Update: prefs:root=General&path=SOFTWARE_UPDATE_LINK
General ⇾ CarPlay: prefs:root=General&path=CARPLAY
General ⇾ Background App Refresh: prefs:root=General&path=AUTO_CONTENT_DOWNLOAD
General ⇾ Multitasking (iPad-only): prefs:root=General&path=MULTITASKING
General ⇾ Date & Time: prefs:root=General&path=DATE_AND_TIME
General ⇾ Keyboard: prefs:root=General&path=Keyboard
General ⇾ Keyboard ⇾ Keyboards: prefs:root=General&path=Keyboard/KEYBOARDS
General ⇾ Language & Region: prefs:root=General&path=INTERNATIONAL
General ⇾ Dictionary: prefs:root=General&path=DICTIONARY
General ⇾ Profiles: prefs:root=General&path=ManagedConfigurationList
General ⇾ Reset: prefs:root=General&path=Reset
```

Control Center

```
Control Center: prefs:root=ControlCenter
Control Center ⇾ Customize Controls: prefs:root=ControlCenter&path=CUSTOMIZE_CONTROLS
```

Display

```
Display: prefs:root=DISPLAY
Display ⇾ Auto Lock: prefs:root=DISPLAY&path=AUTOLOCK
Display ⇾ Text Size: prefs:root=DISPLAY&path=TEXT_SIZE
```

Accessibility

```
Accessibility: prefs:root=ACCESSIBILITY
```

Wallpaper

```
Wallpaper: prefs:root=Wallpaper
```

Siri

```
Siri: prefs:root=SIRI
```

Apple Pencil

```
Apple Pencil (iPad-only): prefs:root=Pencil
```

Face ID

```
Face ID: prefs:root=PASSCODE
```

Emergency SOS

```
Emergency SOS: prefs:root=EMERGENCY_SOS
```

Battery

```
Battery: prefs:root=BATTERY_USAGE
Battery ⇾ Battery Health (iPhone-only): prefs:root=BATTERY_USAGE&path=BATTERY_HEALTH
```

Privacy

```
Privacy: prefs:root=Privacy
Privacy ⇾ Location Services: prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION
Privacy ⇾ Contacts: prefs:root=Privacy&path=CONTACTS
Privacy ⇾ Calendars: prefs:root=Privacy&path=CALENDARS
Privacy ⇾ Reminders: prefs:root=Privacy&path=REMINDERS
Privacy ⇾ Photos: prefs:root=Privacy&path=PHOTOS
Privacy ⇾ Microphone: prefs:root=Privacy&path=MICROPHONE
Privacy ⇾ Speech Recognition: prefs:root=Privacy&path=SPEECH_RECOGNITION
Privacy ⇾ Camera: prefs:root=Privacy&path=CAMERA
Privacy ⇾ Motion: prefs:root=Privacy&path=MOTION\
```

App Store

```
App Store: prefs:root=STORE
App Store ⇾ App Downloads: prefs:root=STORE&path=App%20Downloads
App Store ⇾ Video Autoplay: prefs:root=STORE&path=Video%20Autoplay
```

Wallet

```
Wallet: prefs:root=PASSBOOK
```

Passwords & Accounts

```
Passwords & Accounts: prefs:root=ACCOUNTS_AND_PASSWORDS
Passwords & Accounts ⇾ Fetch New Data: prefs:root=ACCOUNTS_AND_PASSWORDS&path=FETCH_NEW_DATA
Passwords & Accounts ⇾ Add Account: prefs:root=ACCOUNTS_AND_PASSWORDS&path=ADD_ACCOUNT
```

Mail

```
Mail: prefs:root=MAIL
Mail ⇾ Preview: prefs:root=MAIL&path=Preview
Mail ⇾ Swipe Options: prefs:root=MAIL&path=Swipe%20Options
Mail ⇾ Notifications: prefs:root=MAIL&path=NOTIFICATIONS
Mail ⇾ Blocked: prefs:root=MAIL&path=Blocked
Mail ⇾ Muted Thread Action: prefs:root=MAIL&path=Muted%20Thread%20Action
Mail ⇾ Blocked Sender Options: prefs:root=MAIL&path=Blocked%20Sender%20Options
Mail ⇾ Mark Addresses: prefs:root=MAIL&path=Mark%20Addresses
Mail ⇾ Increase Quote Level: prefs:root=MAIL&path=Increase%20Quote%20Level
Mail ⇾ Include Attachments with Replies: prefs:root=MAIL&path=Include%20Attachments%20with%20Replies
Mail ⇾ Signature: prefs:root=MAIL&path=Signature
Mail ⇾ Default Account: prefs:root=MAIL&path=Default%20Account
```

Contacts

```
Contacts: prefs:root=CONTACTS
```

Calendar

```
Calendar: prefs:root=CALENDAR
Calendar ⇾ Alternate Calendars: prefs:root=CALENDAR&path=Alternate%20Calendars
Calendar ⇾ Sync: prefs:root=CALENDAR&path=Sync
Calendar ⇾ Default Alert Times: prefs:root=CALENDAR&path=Default%20Alert%20Times
Calendar ⇾ Default Calendar: prefs:root=CALENDAR&path=Default%20Calendar
```

Notes

```
Notes: prefs:root=NOTES
Notes ⇾ Default Account: prefs:root=NOTES&path=Default%20Account
Notes ⇾ Password: prefs:root=NOTES&path=Password
Notes ⇾ Sort Notes By: prefs:root=NOTES&path=Sort%20Notes%20By
Notes ⇾ New Notes Start With: prefs:root=NOTES&path=New%20Notes%20Start%20With
Notes ⇾ Sort Checked Items: prefs:root=NOTES&path=Sort%20Checked%20Items
Notes ⇾ Lines & Grids: prefs:root=NOTES&path=Lines%20%26%20Grids
Notes ⇾ Access Notes from Lock Screen: prefs:root=NOTES&path=Access%20Notes%20from%20Lock%20Screen
```

Reminders

```
Reminders: prefs:root=REMINDERS
Reminders ⇾ Default List: prefs:root=REMINDERS&path=DEFAULT_LIST
```

Voice Memos

```
Voice Memos: prefs:root=VOICE_MEMOS
```

Phone

```
Phone: prefs:root=Phone
```

Messages

```
Messages: prefs:root=MESSAGES
```

FaceTime

```
FaceTime: prefs:root=FACETIME
```

Maps

```
Maps: prefs:root=MAPS
Maps ⇾ Driving & Navigation: prefs:root=MAPS&path=Driving%20%26%20Navigation
Maps ⇾ Transit: prefs:root=MAPS&path=Transit
```

Compass

```
Compass: prefs:root=COMPASS
```

Measure

```
Measure: prefs:root=MEASURE
```

Safari

```
Safari: prefs:root=SAFARI
Safari ⇾ Content Blockers: prefs:root=SAFARI&path=Content%20Blockers
Safari ⇾ Downloads: prefs:root=SAFARI&path=DOWNLOADS
Safari ⇾ Close Tabs: prefs:root=SAFARI&path=Close%20Tabs
Safari ⇾ Page Zoom: prefs:root=SAFARI&path=Page%20Zoom
Safari ⇾ Request Desktop Website: prefs:root=SAFARI&path=Request%20Desktop%20Website
Safari ⇾ Reader: prefs:root=SAFARI&path=Reader
Safari ⇾ Camera: prefs:root=SAFARI&path=Camera
Safari ⇾ Microphone: prefs:root=SAFARI&path=Microphone
Safari ⇾ Location: prefs:root=SAFARI&path=Location
```

News

```
News: prefs:root=NEWS
```

Health

```
Health: prefs:root=HEALTH
```

Shortcuts

```
Shortcuts: prefs:root=SHORTCUTS
```

Music

```
Music: prefs:root=MUSIC
Music ⇾ Cellular Data: prefs:root=MUSIC&path=com.apple.Music:CellularData
Music ⇾ Optimize Storage: prefs:root=MUSIC&path=com.apple.Music:OptimizeStorage
Music ⇾ EQ: prefs:root=MUSIC&path=com.apple.Music:EQ
Music ⇾ Volume Limit: prefs:root=MUSIC&path=com.apple.Music:VolumeLimit
```

Photos

```
Photos: prefs:root=Photos
```

Camera

```
Camera: prefs:root=CAMERA
Camera ⇾ Record Video: prefs:root=CAMERA&path=Record%20Video
Camera ⇾ Record Slo-mo: prefs:root=CAMERA&path=Record%20Slo-mo
```

Books

```
Books: prefs:root=IBOOKS
```

Game Center

```
Game Center: prefs:root=GAMECENTER
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    About – prefs:root=General&path=About
    Accessibility – prefs:root=General&path=ACCESSIBILITY
     Airplane Mode On – prefs:root=AIRPLANE_MODE
     Auto-Lock – prefs:root=General&path=AUTOLOCK
    Brightness – prefs:root=Brightness
    Bluetooth – prefs:root=General&path=Bluetooth
    Date & Time – prefs:root=General&path=DATE_AND_TIME
    FaceTime – prefs:root=FACETIME
    General – prefs:root=General
     Keyboard – prefs:root=General&path=Keyboard
     iCloud – prefs:root=CASTLE
     iCloud Storage & Backup – prefs:root=CASTLE&path=STORAGE_AND_BACKUP
    International – prefs:root=General&path=INTERNATIONAL
    Location Services – prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES
    Music – prefs:root=MUSIC
    Music Equalizer – prefs:root=MUSIC&path=EQ
    Music Volume Limit – prefs:root=MUSIC&path=VolumeLimit
     Network – prefs:root=General&path=Network
     Nike + iPod – prefs:root=NIKE_PLUS_IPOD
     Notes – prefs:root=NOTES
    Notification – prefs:root=NOTIFICATIONS_ID
     Phone – prefs:root=Phone
    Photos – prefs:root=Photos
     Profile – prefs:root=General&path=ManagedConfigurationList
     Reset – prefs:root=General&path=Reset
    Safari – prefs:root=Safari
    Siri – prefs:root=General&path=Assistant
    Sounds – prefs:root=Sounds
    Software Update – prefs:root=General&path=SOFTWARE_UPDATE_LINK
    Store – prefs:root=STORE
     Twitter – prefs:root=TWITTER
     Usage – prefs:root=General&path=USAGE
    VPN – prefs:root=General&path=Network/VPN
     Wallpaper – prefs:root=Wallpaper
    Wi-Fi – prefs:root=WIFI
```

**BUT** *be warned*, none of it works any more as of yesterday and the iOS5.1 update.

Comment: This is just the same incomplete list that I provided links to in my question. It doesn't include, for example `prefs:root=INTERNET_TETHERING`.

Comment: Beg your pardon, I thought it was expanded, however the pertinent part of the answer still stands.  This no longer works on current software levels.

Comment: Yup. That fact makes my whole question a bit pointless. Hopefully this will get reinstated at some point. It was a very useful feature!

Comment: Works for me with iOS 9.  I wanted to go directly to accessibility and it works great.