# Shortcut app step for activating the Low Data Mode setting when opening an app

Tags: iphone, wifi, settings, automation, shortcuts-app

AIM : When  I open a movie app, such as Netflix or Shudder, I want the Shortcut app to trigger the Low Data Mode setting automatically so that the current movie app is now the only app using the WiFi resources.
(Context: I live up on a mountain, with limited satellite  internet resources.) I do this action myself manually, I would love to automate this action with Shortcuts, but couldn’t see how to . Choosing that particular setting wasn’t available as a triggerable option, it seems?

Comment: Shortcuts doesn’t offer an easy way to enable this in a shortcut or automation, so I think your best option would be to make an automation to open the settings app using the [URL scheme](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/372272/297855) when you open Netflix or Shudder, but I don’t know what the URL would be to get to the specific setting for your WiFi where the low data mode option is located.